# Returning string from Flex after tokenization

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

If I am reading a string with Flex with the following code:

```
     %x str

     %%
             char string_buf[MAX_STR_CONST];
             char *string_buf_ptr;


     \"      string_buf_ptr = string_buf; BEGIN(str);

     <str>\"        { /* saw closing quote - all done */
             BEGIN(INITIAL);
             *string_buf_ptr = '\0';
             /* return string constant token type and
              * value to parser
              */
             }

     <str>\n        {
             /* error - unterminated string constant */
             /* generate error message */
             }

     <str>\\[0-7]{1,3} {
             /* octal escape sequence */
             int result;

             (void) sscanf( yytext + 1, "%o", &result );

             if ( result > 0xff )
                     /* error, constant is out-of-bounds */

             *string_buf_ptr++ = result;
             }

     <str>\\[0-9]+ {
             /* generate error - bad escape sequence; something
              * like '\48' or '\0777777'
              */
             }

     <str>\\n  *string_buf_ptr++ = '\n';
     <str>\\t  *string_buf_ptr++ = '\t';
     <str>\\r  *string_buf_ptr++ = '\r';
     <str>\\b  *string_buf_ptr++ = '\b';
     <str>\\f  *string_buf_ptr++ = '\f';

     <str>\\(.|\n)  *string_buf_ptr++ = yytext[1];

     <str>[^\\\n\"]+        {
             char *yptr = yytext;

             while ( *yptr )
                     *string_buf_ptr++ = *yptr++;
             }
```

Which is taken from [here](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html) and [here](http://www.epaperpress.com/lexandyacc/download/LexAndYaccTutorial.pdf). Now Flex only returns `yytext` or one of the characters in `yytext` but my string is stored in 'string_buf_ptr'. How do I retrieve it in my scanner? As has been pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24968196/1343318), modifying `yytext` beyond current token can cause complications. So what is the to return this string to a simple scanner that does only this:

```
ntoken = yylex();

while(ntoken) {
   prinf("%s\n", yytext);
   ntoken = yylex();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of solutions to this problem, but the only really safe one is to allocate a new string buffer (with `malloc`, usually), fill it in, and pass it to the caller.

If the caller is a bison-generated parser, it will expect the "semantic value" of the token to be in the variable `yylval`, which is most likely a union. In traditional flex/bison scanner/parser arrangements, `yylval` will be a global. That works fine if you only have one scanner and one parser in the program -- and indeed, a huge number of language prototypes have been built in this fasion -- but it's a bit ugly when viewed from a modern programming perspective.

Fortunately, `bison` and `flex` have also evolved, and you can get rid of globals by telling `flex` to build a reentrant lexer and `bison` to build a pure parser. Moreover, you can provide the `bison_bridge` option to `flex` which will cause it to create the correct calling prototype for `yylex` without much more work on your part.

One downside of allocating a new string buffer every time is that you need to free it in your parser. But the upside is that the returned string buffer does not get overwritten on the next call to `yylex`, which makes it possible to use with `bison`. (`bison` and many other parser generators assume that it is possible to read one (or more) tokens in advance.) In that case, you cannot rely on any static state of the lexer, because by the time the `bison` reduction takes place, the lexer has already been called again and discarded the previous state.

The other downside is that you need to maintain the buffer at the correct size. Fortunately, that's easy even if you aren't using C++ strings, which is the strategy I usually recommend to beginners. Here's a very simple buffer management strategy which is surprisingly efficient except on certain platforms whose names begin with W:

```
size_t bf = 0;
char* bfsz = 0;
#define PUTCHAR(ch) do {               \
  char* newbf = realloc(bf, ++bfsz);   \
  if (!newbf) {                        \
    fputs("Out of memory!\n", stderr); \
    exit(2);                           \
  }                                    \
  bf = newbuf;                         \
  bf[bfsz] = ch;                       \
  bf[bfsz+1] = 0;                      \
} while(0)
```

That relies on realloc adjusting the allocation to some exponentially increasing and rapidly doing nothing if there is actually enough space. Many `realloc` implementations work just in that fashion. If `realloc` is no inlined, that code does a lot of extra calls, which slows it down a bit. But it's good enough for quick hacks and you an always improve it later.

Answer (score 0):

if you declare string_buf_ptr as a global, it will be accessible to all of your code without further modification. Probably you'd want to include it e.g. in "myglobals.h" as something like

```
extern char *string_buf_ptr;
```

and include that header file in your flex file (as well as any other code files where the code needs to access string_buf_ptr). Then, before calling main(), declare it e.g.

```
char string_buf_ptr[1024];
```

A potentially better way to do it would be to pass the memory buffer to flex without using a global variable. You can do this using yyextra (for details, see [the Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Extra-Data.html)). The basic approach would be something like:

Create a structure such as

```
struct mystruct {
  char string_buf_ptr[1024]; /* or you can malloc this before calling flex */
};
```

Then before you call yylex, you can do something like:

```
main() {
  ...
  struct mystruct lex_data;
  memset(&lex_data, 0, sizeof(lex_data));
  yylex_init_extra(&lex_data, &yyscanner_pointer);
  ...
  yylex(yyscanner_pointer);
}
```

Then, in your lex code, change references to string_buf_ptr instead to point to

```
((struct mystruct *)yyextra)->string_buf_ptr
```

Feel free to comment if either of those approaches don't work.